# how can set server date config in nuxtjs

Tags: date, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to compare two dates in client .one of them is current date that  its accuracy depends on user system date accuracy .

I use nuxt.js too .is there any way that I set something in nuxt and get date from nuxt(server) in client. 
unfortunately searched alot but find nothing . maybe my search was incorrect .

Comment: What sort of backend do you use. Might be able to get it from there.

Comment: @Andrew1325 yes I can get it but I dont want to rely on backend. prefer to handle it by nuxt if it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `nuxtServerInit` method and generate a timestamp from here:

In `store/index.js`:

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }) {
    commit('setNuxtTime', (new Date()).getTime())
  }
}
```

> If the action `nuxtServerInit` is defined in the store, Nuxt.js will
>   call it with the context (only from the server-side). It's useful when
>   we have some data on the server we want to give directly to the
>   client-side.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: How do you access setNuxtTime on the client side, in this example?